# How to debug issues that require closing the mobile app completely?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have a strange issue that occurs when i close the app completely and remove it from the background process where the Android app crashes for some reason if i open the app with no network connection

If i close the app, the debug will stop and i will not be able to follow the issue.

I am using Visual Studio for Mac and the project in Xamarin Forms but only the Android platform has this issue.

I tried to send crash report since the app is already in Google Play, but there are no crash reports even if i turn on the internet connection and started the app again.

Comment: Pull the crash from `logcat`

Answer (score 0):

you could run:

```
adb -d logcat com.example.example:V > LogRecords.txt 
//com.example.example is a package name, V(verbose) is log level
```

when you finished test, press `ctrl + c` (under windows OS) in command console to stop recording.
Then open LogRecords.txt file to see what happened.